# Stanford Parser

Tags: java, parsing, lisp, common-lisp, stanford-nlp

i parse a string with a java class ( for P.O.S tagging ); the output is a .txt file that i load with this function in lispworks :

```
 (let ((in (open "C:/a.txt" :if-does-not-exist nil)))
   (when in
      (loop for line = (read-line in nil)

      while line do (format t "~a~%" line))
      (close in)
   )
)
```

is there any way to use the java class directly into lisp code ? without doing it separately !

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking about, but the answer is probably "not really".

Comment: Use [Clojure](http://clojure.org/).

Comment: @Karabatich I'm don't know Lisp, but making a simple search i found the [jLinker](http://franz.com/support/documentation/current/doc/jlinker.htm) and according with the documentation : **..."provides a way to execute Java from Lisp"**

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with [Armed Bear Common Lisp (ABCL)](http://abcl.org)?

"Armed Bear Common Lisp (ABCL) is a full implementation of the Common Lisp language featuring both an interpreter and a compiler, running in the JVM.

[…] it can be used to implement (parts of) the application using Java to Lisp integration APIs."